# Dialogflow fulfillment webhook connection fails

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es, chatbot

I'm trying to my app with DialogFlow fulfillment webhook but whenever I make a request it returns:

> POST /webhook 500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR

from ngrok.
I have checked almost everything on dialogflow and ngrok connections and came to nothing

**WebHook URL**

```
https://3aa04ed7.ngrok.io/webhook
```

**main.py**

```
 @app.route('/webhook', methods=['POST'])
def webhook():
    req = request.get_json(silent=True, force=True)

    print("Request:")
    print(json.dumps(req, indent=4))

    res = processRequest(req)
    res = json.dumps(res, indent=4)

    print("Response:")
    print(res)

    response = make_response(res)
    response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
    return response


def processRequest(req):
    print("Processing request")
    result = req.get("result")
    # contexts = result.get("contexts")
    action = result.get("action")

    if action == "givesymptoms":
        return giveSymptoms(req)
    elif action == "followup":
        return followUp(req)
    return result
```

**Terminal Error**

```
Processing request
127.0.0.1 - - [09/Dec/2019 04:56:40] "POST /webhook HTTP/1.1" 500 -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2328, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2314, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1760, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2311, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1834, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1737, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1832, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1818, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\HomeDoctor-master\HomeDoctor-master\main.py", line 41, in webhook
    res = processRequest(req)
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\HomeDoctor-master\HomeDoctor-master\main.py", line 56, in processRequest
    action = result.get("action")
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `processRequest` function

```
result = req.get("result")
```

returning None, So when you try to call get('action') in a None type object it raises ***'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'***

So you can use something like this

```
result = req.get("result", {})
# if there is no key with 'result' in that dict req.get("result", {}) returns {}
action = result.get("action") 
# if there is no key with "action" in result object action carries None type
```